# Jsoup is not finding my element

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but I'm trying to parse this [page](http://feeds.feedburner.com/netsor) using jsoup, it for some reason it doesn't find me the div I'm looking for

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
content = doc.select("div.itemcontent").first().text();
```

Where am I going wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem: you get a different website using jsoup than using a browser. I set another useragent in Jsoup, but no luck. Possible the content is changed through JavaScript?!

However, you can change the selector according to the webseite you get.
It's always a good idea to take a look into document as it's parsed - a simple `System.out.println(doc)` is enough.

Here are some steps you can try:

1. Print your Document `doc` (eg. using `System.out`)
2. Search for the required value(s) in there
3. Select those tags instead

I just played around a bit, but maybe you can use this snipped:

```
content = doc.select("description").first().text();
```

It seems to me, `<description>...</description>` is what you're looking for.